# no mail in `/var/mail`

Tags: monitor, mail, localhost

i am trying to setup my system mail to monitor my `mdadm` raid arrays but I have no mail in `/var/mail`. How can I set this up and how can I test it? There should be something in may mail account I would think but nothing is...

Thanks

**EDIT 1 ** in response to **ANSWER 1**

There's no maillog on my system:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/maillog
tail: cannot open ‘/var/log/maillog’ for reading: No such file or directory
$ echo my test 1 | mail -s test1 root
$
```

I'm using Linux, Kubuntu 14.04 but have no postfix setup, do i need to in order to retrieve system mail?

Answer (score 1):

1) Execute in the first window:

```
tail -f /var/log/maillog
```

2) Execute in the second window:

```
echo my test 1 | mail -s test1 root
```

3) Return to the first window and read displayed lines carefully.

More detailed answer is OS/Distribution/Version-dependent but you don't explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, minimal postfix installation can be done like here:

```
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends postfix
    echo inet_interfaces = loopback-only > /etc/postfix/main.cf
    service postfix start
```

Checking that local SMTP server is active:

```
    netstat -ntlp | grep :25
```

All commands are privileged, so execute "sudo -i" fisrt in console for starting root shell.